# Python - Adding a decimal

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say I have the following function that converts ounces to lbs & oz

```
def oz2lboz(oz):
    oz, lbs = oz - int(oz), int(oz)

    l = lbs * 0.062500
    o = oz

    print "(%d,%d)" % (l,o)
```

Right now, if i was to compute oz2lboz(16), it would give me

```
(1,0)
```

However, I need it to give me,

```
(1,0.0)
```

How would i go about doing that?

Comment: `oz, lbs = oz - int(oz), int(oz)` please don't inline stuff like this if it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Part of the problems you are having are that your conversion isn't quite right. I've adressed this in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the conversion algorithm you have is incorrect.

This line:

```
 oz, lbs = oz - int(oz), int(oz)
```

Sets `oz` to be the value of the decimal portion and disguards the rest and `lbs` to the integer part. Then you multiply the pounds by `1/16`, which in most cases will give you a decimal portion again, which is not usually whats wanted in this type of conversion.

Below we'll alter your original code to return a value to make a point:

```
def oz2lboz(oz):
    oz, lbs = oz - int(oz), int(oz)

    l = lbs * 0.062500
    o = oz
    return (l,o)
```

And call:

```
print "(%d,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(16)
>>> (1,0.0)
print "(%d,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(17)
>>> (1,0.0)
print "(%d,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(18)
>>> (1,0.0)
```

**Well, that isn't right, 16, 17 and 18 oz are all equal to 1 pound!** Lets try again and output the pounds using floats...

```
print "(%.1f,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(16)
>>> (1.0,0.0)
print "(%.1f,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(17)
>>> (1.1,0.0)
print "(%.1f,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(18)
>>> (1.1,0.0)
```

Better, but 17 and 18 are still the same... using more decimal points we get:

```
print "(%.4f,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(16)
>>> (1.0000,0.0)
print "(%.4f,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(17)
>>> (1.0625,0.0)
print "(%.4f,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(18)
>>> (1.1250,0.0)
```

So, basically unless there is a decimal portion you are going to be doing round behind the scenes, because the conversion is off.

Below **I've rewritten your conversion in a correct and slightly simpler way** that again returns the values rather than prints them, so you can output or reuse them as necessary.

```
def oz2lboz(oz):
    lb=int(oz/16)
    oz=float(oz%16)
    return lb,oz
print oz2lboz(17)
```

Which gives this output:

```
(1, 1.0)
```

You can then use normal python [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) to output it as needed, like so:

```
print "(%d,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(17)   #using decimal integer and float formatting
>>> (1,1.0)
print "The baby weighed about, %d pounds and %d ounces." % oz2lboz(42) # just decimals
>>> The baby weighed about, 2 pounds and 10 ounces.
```

Or with our original "problematic" data we get the expected results:

```
print "(%d,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(16)
>>> (1,0.0)
print "(%d,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(17)
>>> (1,1.0)
print "(%d,%.1f)" % oz2lboz(18)
>>> (1,2.0)
```